# Most effective Vagrant workflow, structure?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

So I just started to work with Vagrant and wondering what is most effective structure or workflow. Should I create separate VM for every project or should I use 1 VM to many projects? For example I have 5 WP projects, very different, from landing page to Woocommerce should I separate it or put in one VM. I think putting many projects to 1 VM defeat the purpose of Vagrant in other hand, putting every project to separate VM is some king of overkill or this is normal practice?

Here is the visual example what I'm talking about:

VM per project

[image: VM per project/site]

VM with many projects/vhosts

[image: VM with many projects/vhosts]

So which one is better? Or it's depends from situation and there is no correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or it's depends from situation and there is no correct answer?

I think thats your correct answer !

The best is always to isolate each project from each other specially if they have no dependencies. If you have different php version etc, its best to isolate into a different VM.

on the other side, do you need to work on your 5 projects at the same time ? starting 5 VMs from your host is overkill and you'll run quickly into performance issue (unless you get 64+ GB RAM)

Comment: Thanks, just read more about that and in general best way is keep them separated, you don't usually work with more then 2 projects. No idea why my question was down voted.

Comment: I dunno about the down vote, maybe it was considered primarily opinion-based or there is no straight answers, but there are some 'optimal' ways to work with vagrant